# What are sectional views and cutting plane lines?

Tags: drafting, autocad

I am a student in a Drafting 1 class and we are going over all of the section views (full, half, revolved, offset, etc.) and also all about the cutting planes and different ways for that and how to do them in Autocad. Anyways I'm reading from the book and I still don't understand it very well.  Could someone here explain it well?

Comment: Could you expand on what specific doubts you are having? As-is, this question is far too broad to be answered here.

Comment: What about this is too broad @Wasabi ? There are multiple section views he's enquiring about, but none of them are that complex and could be fairly easily summed up.

Comment: @TrevorArchibald, I think the question would be improved if he explains what he means by "don't understand it very well." I personally am unclear as to whether he is asking about how to do them in AutoCAD or about the concepts themselves.

Comment: @Wasabi According to the title, he's just looking for explanations of the views and lines themselves.

Comment: What is "the book," and if it's just the manual,  why doesn't your class have a basic text on drafting and/or a glossary/cheatsheet with all those terms?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you wanted to show a drawing of a car. You can show the *exterior* features just fine, but how do you show the interior features? If, for instance, you wanted to show where the steering wheel was with respect to the driver's seat, how could you do that?

There are a number of different ways to do it, but the most straightforward is with a *section view*. In a section view, you take an imaginary saw and *cut* the object along a *section plane*. Now you have a cut-open car! Now, if you were to look at the side of the car, the passenger's door, passenger seat, ... the entire passenger's half of the car is gone!

Now all that is left is the *driver's* side of the car, and in looking at it in profile with the passenger's half removed you can now clearly see where the steering wheel lies with respect to the driver's seat.

I put together a crude drawing for you to follow along with below. Note the arrows on the section view - the dashed line shows the person viewing the drawing where the object was cut, and then the arrows show which half you're going to look at. If the arrows pointed down instead of up then you would be looking at the passenger's half of the (American) car.

[image: Section view]

Lastly, notice that hatching /////// or \\\ or XXXXXX that exists in the section view. This shows you which surfaces were cut. Surfaces that are not hatched were not cut. So, in the example above, you could infer that the back seat is maybe a bench seat that spans the width of the car, where the driver's seat is a bucket seat that is not attached.

They're kind of awkward to look at in the beginning, but once you get the concept (cut the object open, then look at the cut surface), then it becomes a lot easier. Section views can show lots of things, but internal features that are otherwise hard to display would be the most common reason I would use a section view.